# Kial monatonomoj estas propraj nomoj sed semajntagoj ne?

Tags: word-usage

En PMEG oni klarigas kial [semajntagojn oni skribas minuskle](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/propraj_nomoj/majuskloj.html#i-smr) sed [monatojn majuskle](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/propraj_nomoj/majuskloj.html#i-klc).

> Monatonomoj (Januaro, Februaro, Marto, Muharamo°, Ramadano k.a.) **estas normalaj propraj nomoj**.  Tradicie, Fundamente kaj Zamenhofe ili estas do skribataj kun komenca majusklo.
>
> [...]
>
> La nomoj de la semajntagoj (lundo, mardo, merkredo k.t.p.) **ne estas propraj nomoj**, kaj estas tial skribataj minuskle.

Ĉu el signifa vidpunkto monatonomoj kaj semajntagoj estas tiel malsamaj kiel por meriti apartan pritrakton?

```
decembro - mardo (en ordo)
Decembro - Mardo (en ordo)
Decembro - mardo (tiun elekton mi ne komprenas)
```

Answer (score 1):

El tiuj lingvoj, kiujn Zamenhof posedis kaj uzis kiel bazon por Esperanto, minimume en la angla kaj la germana oni konsideras la tago- kaj monatonomojn kiel proprajn nomojn. En tiuj lingvoj la monatonomoj bazas sur romiaj dioj kaj la tagonomoj sur ĝermanaj dioj. Ekzemple

- *März/March* ← la dio [Marso](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marso_(dio))
- *Donnerstag/Thursday* ← la dio [Toro](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toro_(mitologio))

Zamenhof elektis uzi la angla-germanajn monatonomojn kaj kopiis la skribmanieron de tiuj lingvoj. Do

- *Marto*

Kompense li elektis la tagonomojn el la franca, la latinida lingvo, kiun li posedis. En la franca oni skribas tiujn minuskle:

- *mardi* → mardo

Sed en multaj aliaj lingvoj, nek la tago- nek la monatonomoj estas propraj nomoj. Certe en la finn-ugraj kaj la nordĝermanaj sed verŝajne ankaŭ en la latinidaj kaj la slavaj oni skribas kaj la tago- kaj la monatonomojn minuskle.

Do tiu nuntempa tendeco skribi la ambaŭajn minuskle, kion PMEG mencias, reflektas tion, kiel la plimulto perceptas la nomojn. Konsekvence

- marto kaj mardo

Comment: Sed tio ne respondas mian demandon: *Kial monatonomoj estas propraj nomoj sed semajntagoj ne?* Tio venas el la Fundamento, do jam tiam estis iu kialo. Sed mi ne sukcesas ĝin trovi.

Comment: Vi pravas, ke mi ne sufiĉe klare klarigis la originon.

Comment: Pli ol la origino, mi ŝatus kompreni la kialon. Eble temas pri io lingva, kiu rilatas nomitajn tempodaŭrojn. Ial Zamenhof elektis la nekongruajn (laŭ mi) formojn Aprilo/mardo. Mi pensis ke PMEG konvinkus min kiel kutime per io solida, sed la decido skribi majuskle monatonomojn kaj minuskle semajtagajn nomojn plu aspektas arbitre.

Comment: Al mi la klarigo en PMEG ŝajnas pardona, kiel defendi arbitran decidon. La sola kialo, kiun mi trovis inter la tekstolinioj estas tiu, kiun mi donis.